No consigo crear un código que pase dígitos de una base a otra
Hola soy nuevo en phyton y estaba experimentando pero me encontre con este problema. Yo creo que lo escribi bien pero no sale bien. Lo que intento es crear un código que pase dígitos de una base a otra. ¡Gracias!
base = input('¿Quieres traducir a binario, decimal o hexadecimal?: ')
x = input('¿Qué texto quieres pasar?: ')
if base == 'binario':
    for c in x:
        print(c, ord(c), bin(ord(c)))
elif base == 'hexadecimal':
    for c in x:
        print(c, ord(c), hex(ord(c)))
elif base == 'decimal':
    for c in x:
        print(c, ord(c), format(ord(c)))        


Hola user, estás trabajando de más... if base == 'binario': print( bin( int( x ))).

input lee texto y con ord obtienes el código Unicode de cada caracter.
Primero tienes que transformar los dígitos en números. Si bien es cierto que ord transforma los dígitos en números, no creo que quieras que "0" se convierta en 48, "1" en 49, "2" en 50, etc.
Si lo que esperas que "0" se transforme en 0, "1" en 1, "2" en 2 y así sucesivamente; tienes que usar la clase int.
base = input('¿Quieres traducir a binario, decimal o hexadecimal?: ')
x = input('¿Qué texto quieres pasar?: ')
if base == 'binario':
    for c in x:
        print(c, bin(int(c)))
elif base == 'hexadecimal':
    for c in x:
        print(c, hex(int(c)))
elif base == 'decimal':
    for c in x:
        print(c, int(c))        

Y si quisieras cambiar la base de partida, puedes agregar un parámetro extra al constructor int indicándola. Por ejemplo de binario a hexadecimal:
hex(int(c, 2))


Hola maestro!!!, el código del OP, no tiene sentido, no se "traduce" un número de un sistema a otro por partes, por lo que el for está sobrando... si ingresas binario y 10, debe devolver 1010 que es "10" en binario.

@Marce al inicio creí que en realidad quería convertir un número. Pero OP dijo que quiere convertir dígitos, o mejor dicho números de un solo dígito. La pregunta no es muy clara al respecto así que decidí hacerlo así.

Releo la pregunta y efectivamente dice "digitos", me sigue pareciendo inverosimil... pero bue, te has apegado a lo que el OP pedía... tu respuesta es correcta.... +1 :)

@Marce simplemente no es claro. Si solo quiere convertir el número a otro sistema de numeración, por qué hablaría de los dígitos.

La función hex(x) devuelve el valor x en su representación hexadecimal.
La función bin(x) devuelve el valor x en su representación binaria.
base = input('¿Quieres traducir a binario, decimal o hexadecimal?: ')
x = int(input('¿Qué texto quieres pasar?: '))
if base == 'binario':
    print(bin(x))
elif base == 'hexadecimal':
    print(hex(x))
elif base == 'decimal':
    print(x)

Prueba
¿Quieres traducir a binario, decimal o hexadecimal?: hexadecimal
¿Qué texto quieres pasar?: 989
0x3dd


Y si quiero pasar ff a decimal ?

@Yussef Mirando el código de la pregunta, sólo pregunta por la base de salida.
